# React onKeyDown/onKeyUp events on non-input elements

Tags: events, reactjs, setstate

I need to capture cmd button up and down events, in order to choose, whether to use concatenation or not in setState. How do i get these events, for example, on table element?

Comment: Alternate solution: [onKeyDown event not working on divs in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503964/onkeydown-event-not-working-on-divs-in-react)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to capture the keypress then in body/window level. Table element doesn't have input focus so you can't capture the keys from table (without input element).

```js
var cmdDown = false;

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode || 0;
  if ([91,93,224,17].indexOf(key) !== -1) {
    cmdDown = true;
  }
  console.log('CMD DOWN: ' + cmdDown.toString());    
});

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode || 0;
  if ([91,93,224,17].indexOf(key) !== -1) {
    cmdDown = false;
  }
  console.log('CMD DOWN: ' + cmdDown.toString());
});
```

Comment: is this the only way to do it?
i have to add listener to body inside componentDidMount?

Comment: React is javascript.. so yes! Just add the listener in `componentDidMount` and remove it when component is unmounting..

Answer (score 3):

#### Simple Example

I believe best practice here is to add an event listener to `document` and modify your element (e.x. table) accordingly. Extending u/Hardy's answer with a full React component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  // Using an arrow function. Alternatively, could bind() this 
  // function in the component's constructor
  keydownHandler = (event) => {
    // Add logic, e.x. check event.keyCode to see 
    // if CMD is pressed and then update state
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keydownHandler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.removeEventListener("keydown", this.keydownHandler);
  }

  render() {
    <div>Hello World</div>
  }
}
```

#### Alternative

As [others have noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503964/onkeydown-event-not-working-on-divs-in-react), there are challenges in using keyboard events that are bound to non-input elements, as browsers require those elements to be in focus in order to invoke the bound callbacks. Another approach that seems to work is to set the `tabindex` property of the component to bring the element in focus. From [u/burak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44434971/1038034):

```
render() {
  <div onKeyDown={this.keydownHandler} tabindex={-1}>Example</div>
}
```

This has the benefit of connecting into [React's Synthetic Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events), that is "a cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event." However, when modifying the `tabindex` property it's important to be mindful that this could change the order of focusable elements, and affect a user's ability to navigate your site with their keyboard or accessibility software. Some users report that setting `tabindex` to `-1` resolves this issue (see comments in previous link).

Comment: this is only part of the solution as it's also affecting input fields

Comment: @BenjaminK could you elaborate?