# How to setState by user's keyboard input in React?

Tags: reactjs, dom, keyboard-events, setstate

I am currently writing a 2048 game which detects user's keyboard input and then change state of the corresponding direction; but I failed to change the state. I use this as a reference to capture the input command. [React onKeyDown/onKeyUp events on non-input elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135912/react-onkeydown-onkeyup-events-on-non-input-elements)
Then setting up a string called keyValue to store the keyboard input's string value and update keyValue in my addEventListener. But I failed to setState by the keyValue in my componentDidMount. My code is as follow. I also tried to setState in my addEventListner earlier but it failed as well. Could anyone help? Thanks.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            board: Array(4).fill().map(x => Array(4).fill(0)),
            score: 0,
            end: false,
            emptySpace: true,
            left: false,
            right: false,
            up: false,
            down: false
        };
    }

   componentDidMount() {
        var cmdDown = false;
        var keyValue = "";
        document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode || 0;
            if ([37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(key) !== -1) {
                cmdDown = true;
                if ([37].indexOf(key) !== -1) {
                    keyValue = "ArrowLeft";
                } else if ([38].indexOf(key) !== -1) {
                    keyValue = "ArrowUp";
                } else if ([39].indexOf(key) !== -1) {
                    keyValue = "ArrowRight";
                } else if ([40].indexOf(key) !== 1) {
                    keyValue = "ArrowDown"
                }
            }
            console.log(keyValue);
            console.log('CMD DOWN: ' + cmdDown.toString());
        });

        document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
            var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode || 0;
            if ([37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(key) !== -1) {
                cmdDown = false;
            }
            console.log('CMD DOWN: ' + cmdDown.toString());
        });
        if (keyValue === "ArrowUp") {
            this.setState({ up: true });
            this.setState({ down: false });
            this.setState({ left: false });
            this.setState({ right: false });
        } else if (keyValue === "ArrowDown") {
            this.setState({ up: false });
            this.setState({ down: true });
            this.setState({ left: false });
            this.setState({ right: false });
        } else if (keyValue === "ArrowLeft") {
            this.setState({ up: false });
            this.setState({ down: false });
            this.setState({ left: true });
            this.setState({ right: false });
        } else if (keyValue === "ArrowRight") {
            this.setState({ up: false });
            this.setState({ down: false });
            this.setState({ left: false });
            this.setState({ right: true });
            console.log(this.state.right)
        }
    }
```

I wrote a function to printout my states. but  inn the log it always print false. Why my state not getting update while render? Are there anything related to synchronization?

```
printDir = () => {
        console.log("up: " + this.state.up.toString());
        console.log("down: " + this.state.down.toString());
        console.log("left: " + this.state.left.toString());
        console.log("right: " + this.state.right.toString());
    }
```

```
 <button onClick = {this.printDir}>dir</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues I can see in your snippet:

1. Your if-else conditions for checking arrow keys are outside of listener setup which won't be triggered
2. You use ES5 function syntax here, `this` object will refer to your function scope, not class scope. You might want to use ES6 arrow function syntax to avoid `this` object scope issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use eventlistener, you have to use `ref` props to access DOM. For the example `<div ref={this.divRef} ...` and in `componentDidMount()` you can write `this.divRef.current.addEventListener('keydown', ...)`